# UITapRecognizer not working on UIView programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am having trouble understanding why when my UIView is tapped, I am not calling my function. My UIView is in my setUpNavBar() What am I doing wrong? My viewDidLoad is a tableView but I have a subview in setUpNavbar which contains my title and image. I first through adding `titleView.isUserInterationEnabled = true` was going to be the fix but that's not the case.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MessageController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()


        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        ref.child("users/profile").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            print(snapshot)
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
//            self.navigationItem.title = dictionary["username"] as? String

                let user = User()
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.setUpNavBar(user: user)

            }
        }, withCancel: nil)

    }

    func setUpNavBar(user: User) {
        let titleView = UIView()

        titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
        titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleView.addSubview(containerView)

        let profileImageView = UIImageView()
        profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        if let profileImageUrl = user.photoURL {
            profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(urlString: profileImageUrl)
        }
        containerView.addSubview(profileImageView)

        profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true


        let nameLabel = UILabel()

        containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.text = user.username
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

        titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let mytapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showChatController))
        mytapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        titleView.addGestureRecognizer(mytapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func showChatController() {
        print("clicked")
//        let chatLogController = ChatLogController()
//        navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `self.navigationItem.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` ?

Comment: Where would that go?

Comment: Before `titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: I get an error. Value of type 'UINavigation' has no member 'isUserInteractionEnabled'

Answer (score 2):

Your `profileImageView` is "eating" the touches. Try disabling its userInteraction.  It should allow touches to be passed on to its parent, `containerView`

```
profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the height and width constraints on your titleView, so its size ends up being (0, 0), with consequently no touchable area.

Try setting the following constraints instead of setting the frame property:

```
    titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    titleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```